# How can I check which branches a TFS 2008 changeset has been merged into?

Tags: tfs

I have some changesets in a TFS 2008 branch which were not merged back into trunk. Time has passed, and now no-one is entirely sure which changesets have made it into trunk. I understand that TFS 2010 allows you to see graphically which branches a changeset has been merged to, but how can I find this out in TFS 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you can you do is use the [TF merge command to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(VS.80).aspx) determine which changesets have not been merged into another branch - one branch at a time.

```
tf merge /recursive /format:brief /candidate $/Branch1 $/Branch2 /preview
```

will  show you what changessets from branch1 are candidates to be merged into branch 2. Of course you can put this into a script to run multiple times.

Comment: That does the trick for me, thanks; fortunately I'm only interested in one branch and trunk, so it was quite straightforward to work out which changesets were missing. Turns out I had almost 6 months of changesets which needed to be merged, and it took me the best part of a week, but at least my branch is now back up to speed.